# problema com a instalação do ubuntu para fazer o dualboot com windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu

durante a instalação do ubuntu ou até mesmo depois de um tempo usando o sistema que está no pendrive começa a dá o erro abaixo.

> `pcie bus error severity=corrected type=physical layer id=00e8(receiver id)`

configurações de hardware

marca hp

hd 500gb

ssd 128gb

i3 6 geração

texto em negrito

Comment: Computadores da hp não funcionam direito com linux, você só vai ter dor de cabeça tentando instalar. Experiencia própria.

Comment: encontrei o mesmo caso do meu de 2018 e 05/2019, e não encontrei solução. Até me conformei que o cara  tentou com 8 distribuições linux e nada.

Comment: Eu tentei todas as distribuições possíveis, postei no fórum VOL e nada até hoje

Comment: https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Linux-Avancado/Tentativa-de-instalar-Linux-em-um-notebook-HP-240-G6

Comment: foi por causa de você que me conformei, entendi que o problema não era eu e sim o notebook. Isso serve como lição para não comprar mais pcs da hp para usar linux.